# CSS header styling

Tags: css, html, header, styling

Just wondering how to style a header like the attached image. Was thinking of using two divs, the left for the text and the right for the horizontal repeating image. Problem is I need the right div's width to change with respect to different header lengths.

Any help would be appreciated!

[header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZzrY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in simple;

```
.header{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background:url('http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png') repeat;
}
.header span{
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 20px;
}

<div class="header"><span class="title">Header Text</span></div>
```

You can include this in various pages and the title space re-size accordingly.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/2rDGc/)*** is a working Live Demo

Answer (score 1):

Use left and right `DIVs` with respective `width` and then to the `right div` use `text-align: right;` property so that the content loaded in right div will remain to right and increase to left depending on the size of content

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.header{overflow: hidden;} //Considering width: 1000px;
.left{float: left; width: 100px;}
.right{float: right; width: 900px; text-align: right;}
```

Comment: As the headers are generated by a wordpress themes backend, the left divs width will always be different so I wouldn't know the width.  @blasteralfred suggested a working demo that re-sizes accordingly. Thanks for the help......

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with just a `<h1>` tag for semantic reasons, and ad a background-image to it.
With padding-right you now can control the amount of how many times it should repeat itself and filling up the needed space.